# Country from multiple IP

Tags: ip-address, country

I have a stats page which can only run from console and would like to display the country name of each visitor to my website from the reported IP address.

I've included a sample page showing code of 3 IP addresses (in reality there are more resulting from a database query. I've simplified it here so you can see what I am seeing.

My apologies, I am using classic ASP and VBScript.

My problem is that I cannot get it to go through the 3 addresses. The result seems to be showing random results and not always resulting with the correct IP address.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
<%
Session("Origin_Address1") = "8.8.8.8"        ' US
Session("Origin_Address2") = "92.251.87.224"  ' MT
Session("Origin_Address3") = "60.145.166.1"   ' JP

do until T = 3
T = T + 1
Origin_Address = Session("Origin_Address"&T)
%>
  <script>
    $.ajax({
        url: "https://geoip-db.com/jsonp/<%=Origin_Address%>",
        jsonpCallback: "callback",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        success: function( location ) {
            $('#country<%=T%>').html(location.country_name);
        }
    });     
  </script>
  <div><%=T & " - " & Origin_Address & " - "%><span id="country<%=T%>"></span></div>
<%
 loop
%>  
 </body>
</html>
```

I wish the results to be as shown below:

1 - 8.8.8.8 - United States

2 - 92.251.87.224 - Malta

3 - 60.145.166.1 - Japan

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing? No one?
My 6th post and never received a reply from anyone :(